# Get usergroups from multiple RD Collections

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

I have a situation !

I need to gather the usergroup(s) from various remote desktop session collections.

I need the Output in CSV with following header

Connection_Broker, Collection_Name, UserGroups

After fetching the usergroups across collections, need to append the existing usergroups with a <new_usergroup>

This is what i have tried..

```
# List of Connection Brokers
$CBs = Get-Content .\CBs.txt
$CN = (Get-RDRemoteDesktop -ConnectionBroker $CB | Where-Object { $_.ShowInWebAccess -eq "True" }).CollectionName
# Check for collections published in RD Web
foreach ($CB In $CBs) {
  get-rdsessionCollectionConfiguration -ConnectionBroker $CB -CollectionName $CN -UserGroup
   
}
Write-Host $CN 'is on' $CB
```

Comment: Create a table using : $table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new().  Than add each collection in the foreach : $table += get-rdsessionCollectionConfiguration -ConnectionBroker $CB -CollectionName $CN -UserGroup

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `$CN = ...` line **inside** the loop. Where it is now, variable `$CB` has no value.
Then, if you want the info gathered saved as csv file, you need to have the loop output **objects** you can capture in a variable.

Try

```
# List of Connection Brokers
$CBs = Get-Content .\CBs.txt
# Check for collections published in RD Web
$result = foreach ($CB In $CBs) {
    $CN = (Get-RDRemoteDesktop -ConnectionBroker $CB | Where-Object { $_.ShowInWebAccess -eq "True" }).CollectionName
    Get-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration -ConnectionBroker $CB -CollectionName $CN -UserGroup | ForEach-Object {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Connection_Broker = $CB
            Collection_Name   = $CN
            UserGroup         = $_   # or whatever property you want from this object
        }
    }
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# export to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\WhereEver\usergroups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```